# Is it possible to deploy an app to iPhone of newer version than it was built for?

Tags: iphone

Could you please help me clarify the following.

I'm aware of deployment target option, but what about forward compatibility?
I currently build my iPhone app with base sdk version of 4.0. Is it generally possible to deploy such ipa image (built against an older sdk) via iTunes to a new iPhone 4.1 device for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you deploy using iTunes via downloading from the App store, or via an Ad Hoc build and provision, then yes.

However the old SDK 4.0 Xcode installation will not directly deploy apps to an iOS 4.1 device from the Organizer or Debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. Otherwise every single app would have to be recompiled whenever Apple released a new OS version.